# Trouble with progressbar in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, progress-bar

i m facing problem in giving animation to progressbar in QT.

where is the mistake in the following code, i am getting continues progress bar, but its not animating

```
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();


QProgressBar *pbar = new QProgressBar(dialog);

pbar->setMinimum(0);
pbar->setMaximum(0);
pbar->setTextVisible(false);

QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();
QRect rect = desktop->geometry();

pbar->setGeometry(rect.left(),rect.top(),rect.right(),rect.bottom()-300);

pbar->show();


dialog->setBar(pbar);

dialog->showMaximized(); 
dialog->exec();   
return a.exec();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this code on WinXP with Qt 4.5.3 and it works as expected.
I cannot give you a solution but i have a suggestion:
You don't need to set a QProgressBar to QProgressDialog, it already has its own.

Removing the code for QProgressBar, the code below does the same thing with your original code on my machine.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();

dialog->setMinimum(0);
dialog->setMaximum(0);

dialog->showMaximized(); 
dialog->exec();   
return a.exec();
```

Comment: Hey i got it..Thanks for ur suggestion
the thing is.. ur code is also behaving like the code above mine..

in my emulator i m getting progress bar, with the zigzag style.. i.e while blue..but its static.. i mean its not moving..

emulator behaviour is like that only or what?

Comment: Hmm, i have never worked with symbian but that seems like somethig an emulator can do. Can you try deploying it on an actual symbian machine to try?

Comment: ya.. ill try in mobile and tell u :)
Thanks

Comment: Hey.. i tried in mobile.
its not animating.. just static progress bar is showing

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Windows Vista theme (QWindowsVistaStyle) then there's a bug that means indeterminate progress bars don't animate. I've written up the bug here, complete with simple patch: http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-10984

Comment: i found the solution for the problem.
may i know which version of Qt are you using?, Qt say issue is fixed in Qt 4.6.2

Comment: This was going wrong for me in the 4.7 tech preview. Perhaps it's a different problem to what you're seeing.

Answer (score -2):

Dudes, what exactly do you think that a progress bar does? It is supposed to show the user that an activity is ongoing and also what is the current progress state.

Your code

```
QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();

dialog->setMinimum(0);

dialog->setMaximum(0);
```

would indicate that a certain operation will start with status 0 and will end when the status (or current value) reaches value ... 0. And you want some animation going with that?

See an example at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprogressdialog.html#details

Basically you should create a progress dialog with a min and a max value

```
QProgressDialog *dialog = new QProgressDialog();

dialog->setMinimum(0);

dialog->setMaximum(100);
```

Then have the actual progress value updated (e.g. on a timer which triggers the perform slot) in order to have it represented in the progress bar:

```
void Operation::perform()
{
     dialog->setValue(steps);
     //... perform one percent of the operation
     steps++;
     if (steps > dialog->maximum())
         t->stop();
}
```

A series of updates, with progressively increasing progress value, will create the animation effect you want.

Obviously tagging this with Symbian is pure wrong, this is not at all Symbian specific. Nor is it Qt 4.x specific, hell ... it's not even Qt specific, it's basically a logic issue. ;)

Comment: Actually these days progress bars also can be used to show that the application is still doing something but the progress can't be estimated. This is animated and called marquee mode ( or knightrider mode). Setting the min and max to 0 does this in Qt.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip. I see something like that on Windows but it is not documented behaviour.